# Installing python modules like "Web3" without pip/pip3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, cross-platform, web3py

I have an armv7 embedded device. There is a yocto linux running on this device. There is no pip installed in it so i cannot install web3 using ..

```
pip install web3
```

How can I install web3 or any python module without using pip? I have tried searching the recipe of web3.py but couldn't find any.

Can I cross compile the web3 module? how to do that?

how can build from source work for this module?

what about the other dependencies required for it?

I am not a full time Linux or python developer so please tell me about the first step I need to follow?

Comment: download `get_pip.py` and install `pip`.

Comment: You can also try to build from source, if it is available

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py.. I think build from source is not available..

Comment: if module uses only code in Python then there is nothing to compile and you could download it and use it. My may add folder with module to `sys.path` before `import`

Comment: it seems it use only code in Python so there is no compile and you can use it at once. After download you can eventually use `python setup.py install`

Comment: Thanks..let me try..

Comment: if you wil have your script and folder web3  in the same folder then it should `import web3` without installation.

Comment: here you can download `get-pip.py` and install `pip`: https://github.com/pypa/get-pip

Comment: i have this missing package for get-pip.py ImportError: No module named pkgutil

Comment: python setup.py install also gave me alot of error about missing libraries..

Comment: importing it from a same folder gave this error back.. ImportError: No module named 'eth_account'

Answer (score 1):

You can just download the module (web3 folder from [the repo](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py)), put it in your project directory and import it (so you can use it).

The problem is that the module can have some dependencies on other modules, so the problem is not resolved.

I think that the best solution for you is [download and install pip from source](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

Comment: for python3 it gives error ImportError: No module named 'getpass'

Comment: and for python2 :ImportError: No module named pkgutil